# Google Maps take a long time to load

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

when i try to load my custom-made app, it takes a long time before it locates me. I know it would be dependent on the Network Provider and the GPS. But some Apps like [Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC5hcHBzLm1hcHMiXQ..) locate me much faster (with the same setting and device). Is it because I am trying out stuffs from a free source? Will a subscribed map API from Google Inc load the map faster?

Does anybody experience the same problem? Any thoughts on the solution?

Comment: Have you enabled both Google's Location Service and GPS in your app?

Comment: yes of course. Nevertheless, tested on both cases, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

If it eventually grabs your location, it's not your fault it's going slow (unless you have the requestLocationUpdates() delay set obnoxiously high, which is doubtful). I've been using the GPS in several of my apps, and I've seen it take less than a second for a location fix, but I've also seen it take over 10 minutes on other devices.

I don't think it's a problem with your maps, though. Sure, maybe Google's map API loads a tiny bit faster; but I don't think that's your issue here.

Comment: Lucky you, that you get ur location fix in few seconds! :-)
the requestLocationUpdates is set to work with 0 seconds as minimum update time and 0 as the minimum distance to update.

Comment: That's what I have all of mine set to as well, but as I said, with the same settings I've seen it take upwards of 10 minutes (as a side note: I also checked Google Maps on the same devices this happened, and it took a long time for a location fix there as well). But basically, it's not your fault and as far as I know there's nothing we can really do about it since it's a GPS/network issue, not your app's

Comment: @Cruceo I just came across the same problem. Is there a way to store the map locally..??

Comment: @suja I'm sure there is, but that would be a LOT of data. You could try just storing the Location's LAT/LONG in your SharedPreferences, but that does not guarantee the location will always be accurate (it'll just prevent it from being null after the first time). What I ended up doing was using Google Play Services to handle all Location-related things, as it's pretty well built, easy to use, and way friendlier than coding from scratch, and all devices with Play Store access should have it already installed: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html